# Why was my question migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, superuser

Why was my question migrated to Super User?

Since the question has migrated, it seems nobody has viewed my question and haven't got any answer for past 2 days.

Here is the link to the question:

[Internet Connection Sharing - Connecting 2 computers to share internet](https://superuser.com/questions/280379/internet-connection-sharing-connecting-2-computers-to-share-internet)

Comment: It is not a programming question.

Comment: Apparently you do not understand the whole "on topic" concept.

Comment: Your question has an answer now, at least! :)

Answer (score 13):

When it comes to "where does my question belong" I typically compare the FAQs of the potential sites since those outline the proper question topics.

Here is Stack Overflow's:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So, not a lot of hits there.  This isn't a programming problem nor is it anything unique to programming or the tools related to programming.

Here is Super User's:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

This is certainly about computer hardware/software, which matches with Super User better than Stack Overflow, so it belongs there.

Migration isn't a penalty or anything, it just helps questions get to the right place when the asker doesn't necessarily know any better.  The Super User community will be better equipped to help you with your problem than Stack Overflow would.

Answer (score 5):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Stack Overflow is [a Q&A site] for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Note that your question was *not* related to programming at all (and no, "using computers" is very different from "programming"), therefore it was 1) ignored as off-topic and later 2) correctly migrated to Super User, which, according to *its* FAQ, is a site

> for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>   - computer hardware
>   - computer software

(And your second question was not related to programming either; as it was related to the workings of Stack Overflow, it was migrated here, to Meta Stack Overflow - the Q&A site for questions *about* Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Note however, that questions about "the Q&A site for questions _about_ Stack Overflow" should still stay directed here. There's only one level of indirection available. Alternately, asking in chat is a close second, but usually by the time you both know about chat and can participate, you don't ask these sorts of questions anymore.